# Vertically aligning the text of two adjacent tds

Tags: html, css

I have a table with two tds to each row. I've come to notice that if I wanted to line break the text the text inside the opposite td does not vertically align to it. The td with the line break goes to the top of the cell where the other stays vertically aligned to the center. What would be the most effective solution in keeping both center and having their baselines equally aligned?

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/653K2/2/

**HTML**

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Category One</td>
   <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Category Two</td>
   <td>Data<br>More Data</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
table tr td:first-child {
    color: #777;
    width: 40%;
}
tr {
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #e6e6e6;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain based on this example? http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=2FhSnwcj7C

Comment: @AlexDresko Sure. Notice how the text inside the second td of the second tr doesn't align to the baseline of the first? That's what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Still I am not clear with you.

Comment: Me either. Can you go to the fiddle and chat with us on there? There are several of us waiting to help.

Comment: Else put some snapshots that would make your idea clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
td {padding: 10px 0; vertical-align: top;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/653K2/4/

Comment: In order to prevent the text from hitting the top of the cell, padding to the top and bottom of the td had to be applied.

Comment: This was not the issue as you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/653K2/5/ (nothing that bad in the demo than cannot be re-designed) but the alignment was the missing recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is to add to your css

```
td {vertical-align: baseline}
```

replace baseline with one of [baseline, top, center, bottom]

Comment: Well that was fun. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a vertical-align property on css, is this what you want?

```
td { text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:0}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/653K2/3/